# How to convert JSON to tsv format using jq

Tags: jq

Given following json content ,

```
{
    
    "application": "grafana",
    "users": {
        "admin": {
             "display-name": "admin",
             "access": "admin"
        },
        "user1": {
             "display-name": "user1",
             "access": "read"
        },
        "user2": {
             "display-name": "user2",
             "access": "edit"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to produce tsv format like following :

```
Application  User   Access
grafana      admin  admin
             user1  read
             user2  edit
```

How can I use jq @tsv to achieve that ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? jq already has a `@tsv` filter. Why does only admin have an application but the other users do not?

Comment: the application is common to all users,  it just instead of displaying same application in every row, I want to only display it in first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to only display application name in first row ?

One could utilize the facts that `transpose` compensates for a rigged matrix using `null` values, and that `@tsv` gracefully translates `null` values to empty strings:

```bash
[["Application"], ["User"], ["Access"]],
[[[.application]], [.users[] | [."display-name", .access]]]
| transpose[] | flatten(1) | @tsv
```

The same without butchering the headers array:

```bash
["Application", "User", "Access"], (
  [[[.application]], [.users[]|[."display-name",.access]]]
  | transpose[] | flatten(1)
) | @tsv
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that prints the application in every row (not quite what you asked):

```
["Application", "User", "Access"],
[.application] + (.users[]|[."display-name",.access])
| @tsv
```

or:

```
["Application", "User", "Access"],
(.application as $app | .users[] | [$app,."display-name",.access])
| @tsv
```

Output:

```
Application User    Access
grafana admin   admin
grafana user1   read
grafana user2   edit
```

Here's a very crude way to have the application only printed for the first user. Im pretty sure there's a better way.

```
["Application", "User", "Access"],
(
    .application as $app
    | [.users[]]
    | .[].application = null
    | .[0].application = $app
    | .[]
    | [.application,."display-name",.access]
)
| @tsv
```

I wonder though if this is worth the effort, because parsing the TSV will then require additional extra rules instead of simply having app,name,access in each line. In other words: having the app only in the first line complicates the writing *and* the reading part of the data

Comment: thanks, is there a way to only display application name in first row ?

Comment: @AndyWu I found a way. See my updated answer, even though I would recommend the first option.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use jq just to extract the raw tsv and the use another tool for the fine-tuning:

```bash
jq -r '[.application] + (.users[] | [."display-name", .access]) | @tsv' file.json \
| awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"; print "Application", "user", "Access"}
    NR > 1 {$1 = ""}
    {print}
' \
| column -ts $'\t'
```

```
Application  user   Access
grafana      admin  admin
             user1  read
             user2  edit
```

This assumes you use GNU `column` and bash (for ASNI-C quoting `$'\t'`)